# Algorithm for comparing pictures/shapes for uniqueness

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Say that you have a grid where users draw pictures/shapes by clicking and coloring the boxes. Can you suggest any algorithm to compare these drawings according to originality ? I was thinking about comparing them according to the boxes they occupy but I am not sure if that is the best way. I hope I was clear. Thanks.

Comment: "originality" is very subjective! Can you define it? I can't!

Comment: I guess you are right. Let's say maybe being different then others.I need to pick one of the drawings. How would you pick one by comparing them in a fair way ? That's what I am wondering.

Comment: This question is way to vague. Please provide examples (pictures) of what you mean by "originality".

Comment: @Cemre- Can you please give a **specific** definition of uniqueness?  Right now your question is too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best choice would be to use mutual information as a metric. Since this is still a very abstract problem I am not sure about details of calculating it.

Let me elaborate on why mutual information is a good measure. Let us assume a image is made up of colors a,b,c and 4 (exactly four colors). And another image is exactly same, except a is replaced with e, b->f, c->g and d->h. If you use any other metrics (correlation for example), these two images seem dissimilar, but mutual information would show that these two images share exact same information (only coded differently).

How to calculate mutual information: First, you need to align the images (which is a tough problem, you can get reasonable solution by transforming the image in offsets, scaling and rotation). Once images are aligned, you have pixel-to-pixel relation. You can assume each pixel is independent and calculate I(X;Y) where X is pixel from first image and Y from second. This is the simple-most solution, but you can assume more complicate relations Eg: I(X1,...,Xk;Y1,...,Yk) where X1,...,Xk are adjacent pixels and Yis correspond to their counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special curve in math. Such a curve fills the space and traverse each point exactly once. Thus you can reduce the 2d complexity you have a problem to a 1d complexity. When you sort the points you can see the image in 1 dimension this makes it easer to apply a statistical algorithm to look for similarities. You can apply this to each color of the image.